# urls.E004 path not working in Python Django

Tags: python, django

So, everytime I try to run the server it sends this error:

> ?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern b'["Aquaman", "Glass", "Bumblebee", "Polar", "Bohemian Rhapsody", "Widows", "Creed II", "Escape Room", "Dragon Ball Super: Broly", "Mortal Engines", "6.9", "6.9", "6.5", "6.4", "8.2", "6.7", "6.6", "6.6", "7.5", "5.9", "297802", "450465", "424783", "483906", "424694", "401469", "480530", "522681", "503314", "428078", "143", "129", "114", "119", "135", "130", "130", "100", "101", "128", "Action", "Thriller", "Action", "Action", "Drama", "Crime", "Drama", "Horror", "Action", "Science Fiction"]' is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of path() and/or re_path() instances.

This is the code

```
import requests
import json
from django.conf.urls import url, include, re_path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from django.urls import path

def lookForValue(value, list, moves, number_of_values):
    i = 0
    valuesFound = []
    for string in list:
        if string == value and i < number_of_values:
            pointer = list.index(string)
            valuesFound.append(list[pointer + moves])
            i += 1
            list[pointer] = None
    return valuesFound


def getData(apiurl):
    payload = {}
    data = requests.request("GET", apiurl, data=payload)
    data = data.text
    data = data.split('\"')
    return data


url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=31563efa3563f61e00e5f0e2ed88c4bb&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1"
list = getData(url)
titles = []
release_dates = []
ratings = []
uids = []
runtimes = []
genres = []
total = []
i = 0
j = 0


titles = lookForValue('title', list, 2, 10)
release_dates = lookForValue('release_date', list, 2, 10)
ratings = lookForValue('vote_average', list, 1, 10)
uids = lookForValue('id', list, 1, 10)


for string in ratings:
    ratings[ratings.index(string)] = string[1:4]

for string in uids:
    uids[uids.index(string)] = string[1:7]

for string in uids:
    response = getData('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + string + '?api_key=31563efa3563f61e00e5f0e2ed88c4bb&language=en-US')
    genres.append(lookForValue('genres',response, 6, 1)[0])
    runtimes.append(lookForValue('runtime', response,1, 1)[0])


for i in range(0, 10):
    runtimes[i] = runtimes[i][1:len(runtimes[i])]
    runtimes[i] = runtimes[i][0:len(runtimes[i]) - 1]


total += titles
total += ratings
total += uids
total += runtimes
total += genres



def createJsonResponse(object):
    return JsonResponse(object, safe = False)


urlpatterns = [
    path('popularmovies',  include(createJsonResponse(total)))
]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `include`'s first argument should be name of the module not the functions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#include

Comment: So, I did what you said and it worked. Thank you for the solution and the snark,